# My joins mutiplies my sum results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I trying to do this query but the results mutiplies by 4x
This field is a Time type, maybe that's the problem?
anyway the wrong results show up when I join the other tables, every join add 1 time more to the result.

I manipulate the table to match the results, I expect in 40000 in the sum but when I run the query that show 160000;

This is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(tempoexposicao) AS exposicao 
FROM tb_programacao
INNER JOIN tb_go ON tb_programacao.cod_go=tb_go.cod_go
INNER JOIN tb_funcionario ON tb_go.equi_func1_mat=tb_funcionario.matricula_qt 
INNER JOIN tb_horario ON tb_horario.cod_funcionario=tb_funcionario.cod 
WHERE tb_funcionario.cod=1 
AND tb_programacao.data="2013-12-18"
AND tb_programacao.cod_go=1 
AND tb_programacao.codprogramacao=1
GROUP BY tb_programacao.item;
```

My tables:

```
tb_programação 
cod codprogramacao cod_go  obra                   item tempoexposicao
1   |1              |1       |QUALIFICAÇÃO SOLDADOR  |1    |01:00:00.000000
2   |1              |1       |QUALIFICAÇÃO SOLDADOR  |1    |01:00:00.000000

tb_go
cod cod_go projeto                  equi_func1_mat
1   |1     |QUALIFICACAO DE SOLDADOR|0677

2   |1     |HCC 066/12              |0677

tb_funcionario  
cod matricula_qt nome 
1  |0677        |ABEL ALBUQUERQUE FERREIRA

tb_horario  
cod cod_funcionario data
1   |2               |2014-01-01

3   |1               |2014-01-01
```

Finally I solved, thx guys
that's the query I want

```
SELECT (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(tempoexposicao))) 
    FROM tb_programacao AS t2 
    WHERE t2.item = t.item
    ) AS exposicao
FROM tb_programacao as t
    INNER JOIN tb_go ON t.cod_go=tb_go.cod_go
    INNER JOIN tb_funcionario ON tb_go.equi_func1_mat=tb_funcionario.matricula_qt 
    INNER JOIN tb_horario ON tb_horario.cod_funcionario=tb_funcionario.cod 
WHERE tb_funcionario.cod=1
    AND t.cod_go IS NOT NULL
    AND t.data="2013-12-18"
    AND t.cod_go=1 
    AND t.codprogramacao=1
GROUP BY t.clie_cod
ORDER BY CAST( t.cod_go AS SIGNED INTEGER ) ASC
```

Comment: Usually when an inner join returns more results than the original table the cause is that you missed fields in the join clause, the primary key of the second table has more fields, so you have to identify that fields and and it to the ON clause.

Comment: The normal reason for multiplying results is that the joins are multiplying the number of rows.  A good solution is to move the sub into a subquery in the `from` clause.  However, you don't provide enough information to fix this, because you don't state where `tempoexposicao` comes from.

Comment: Ok, I will update now and put the fields and tables in this query too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what happens When you remove this part from your query

```
AND tb_programacao.data="2013-12-18"
```

You can also try this

```
SELECT SUM(tb_programacao.tempoexposicao) AS exposicao 
FROM tb_programacao
INNER JOIN tb_go ON tb_programacao.cod_go=tb_go.cod_go
INNER JOIN tb_funcionario ON tb_go.equi_func1_mat=tb_funcionario.matricula_qt 
INNER JOIN tb_horario ON tb_horario.cod_funcionario=tb_funcionario.cod 
WHERE tb_funcionario.cod=1 
AND tb_programacao.data="2013-12-18"
AND tb_programacao.cod_go=1 
AND tb_programacao.codprogramacao=1
GROUP BY tb_programacao.item;
```

Comment: still the same result if I remove

Comment: Take screenshots of your database tables(in edit mode)  and put them up somewhere that we can browse to . That will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

If we have your database schema, you get better answer. 
You can try to execute this query.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(tempoexposicao) 
    FROM tb_programacao AS t2 
    WHERE t2.item = t.item
    ) AS exposicao
FROM tb_programacao as t
    INNER JOIN tb_go ON t.cod_go=tb_go.cod_go
    INNER JOIN tb_funcionario ON tb_go.equi_func1_mat=tb_funcionario.matricula_qt 
    INNER JOIN tb_horario ON tb_horario.cod_funcionario=tb_funcionario.cod 
WHERE tb_funcionario.cod=1 
    AND t.data="2013-12-18"
    AND t.cod_go=1 
    AND t.codprogramacao=1
GROUP BY t.item;
```

Comment: Thx! u helped a lot with this subquery

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting multiple matches from the joins which increases your joined result set.

A quick way to check this would be to remove the sum to reveal the raw rows of results.

Looking at your sample data provided, there are multiple matches between tb_programacao and tb_go if cod_go is the only key for the join. This alone could double your sum result. So adding more conditions to get a unique key for the join will help. E.g join on both cod_go and cod?